# Using HeroCard Carsousel in first step of waterfall is not proceeding the further step

Tags: botframework, chatbot

I am using a waterfall method which will create a service request for me. In the first step of waterfall, i am showing the list of herocards as carousel for service request creation.

```
const srCarousel = [
                CardFactory.heroCard('Application Service Request',
                    CardFactory.images(['https://www.usnews.com/dims4/USNEWS/65f1856/2147483647/thumbnail/970x647/quality/85/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fcom-usnews-beam-media.s3.amazonaws.com%2Fbe%2Fdd%2F8f25b4174b6398285139452fb7d5%2F190313-collegeapplication-stock.jpg']),
                    CardFactory.actions([
                        { type: 'postBack',
                            title: 'Application Service Request',
                            value: 'Create Application Service Request'
                        }])),
                CardFactory.heroCard('Virtual Desktop Service Request', ['https://www.usnews.com/dims4/USNEWS/65f1856/2147483647/thumbnail/970x647/quality/85/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fcom-usnews-beam-media.s3.amazonaws.com%2Fbe%2Fdd%2F8f25b4174b6398285139452fb7d5%2F190313-collegeapplication-stock.jpg'], ['Create Virtual Desktop Service Request']),
                CardFactory.heroCard('Generic Service Request', ['https://www.usnews.com/dims4/USNEWS/65f1856/2147483647/thumbnail/970x647/quality/85/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fcom-usnews-beam-media.s3.amazonaws.com%2Fbe%2Fdd%2F8f25b4174b6398285139452fb7d5%2F190313-collegeapplication-stock.jpg'], ['Create Generic Service Request'])

            ];
            const message = MessageFactory.carousel(srCarousel);
            return await stepContext.context.sendActivity(message);
```

The above code is first function in my waterfall method. However when i invoke this dialog. I am getting the carousel card in emulator but the bot is moving to final step instead of next prompt. Could anyone please assist. I even tried with action type as postback , messageBack . it didn't work out for me.

Update :

My complete Waterfall dialog step :

```
class CreateServiceRequestDialog extends CancelAndHelpDialog {
    constructor(id) {
        super(id || 'createServiceRequestDialog');

        // this.IncReq = new IncReq('int_user', 'Admin@123');

        this.addDialog(new TextPrompt(TEXT_PROMPT))
            .addDialog(new ConfirmPrompt(CONFIRM_PROMPT))
            .addDialog(new ChoicePrompt(CHOICE_PROMPT))
            .addDialog(new DateResolverDialog(DATE_RESOLVER_DIALOG))
            .addDialog(new WaterfallDialog(WATERFALL_DIALOG, [
                this.serviceRequestTypes.bind(this),
                this.classifySRDialog.bind(this)
                // this.incidentCreation.bind(this)
            ]));
        this.initialDialogId = WATERFALL_DIALOG;
    }

    async serviceRequestTypes(stepContext) {
        const srTypes = stepContext.options;
        console.log('INSIDE SR TYPES');
        console.log(srTypes);
        if (!srTypes.srTypes) {
            const srCarousel = [
                CardFactory.heroCard('Application Service Request',
                    CardFactory.images(['https://www.usnews.com/dims4/USNEWS/65f1856/2147483647/thumbnail/970x647/quality/85/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fcom-usnews-beam-media.s3.amazonaws.com%2Fbe%2Fdd%2F8f25b4174b6398285139452fb7d5%2F190313-collegeapplication-stock.jpg']),
                    CardFactory.actions([
                        { type: 'postBack',
                            title: 'Application Service Request',
                            value: 'Create Application Service Request'
                        }])),
                CardFactory.heroCard('Virtual Desktop Service Request', ['https://www.usnews.com/dims4/USNEWS/65f1856/2147483647/thumbnail/970x647/quality/85/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fcom-usnews-beam-media.s3.amazonaws.com%2Fbe%2Fdd%2F8f25b4174b6398285139452fb7d5%2F190313-collegeapplication-stock.jpg'], ['Create Virtual Desktop Service Request']),
                CardFactory.heroCard('Generic Service Request', ['https://www.usnews.com/dims4/USNEWS/65f1856/2147483647/thumbnail/970x647/quality/85/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fcom-usnews-beam-media.s3.amazonaws.com%2Fbe%2Fdd%2F8f25b4174b6398285139452fb7d5%2F190313-collegeapplication-stock.jpg'], ['Create Generic Service Request'])

            ];
            const message = MessageFactory.carousel(srCarousel);
            return await stepContext.context.sendActivity(message);
        }
    }

    async classifySRDialog(stepContext) {
        stepContext.values.classifiedSR = stepContext.result;
        console.log(stepContext.values.classifiedSR );
        if (stepContext.values.classifiedSR === 'Create Generic Service Request') {
            const promptOptions = { prompt: 'Can you describe your service request in short' };
            return await stepContext.prompt(TEXT_PROMPT, promptOptions);
        } else if (stepContext.values.classifiedSR === 'Create Application Service Request') {
            console.log('Inside Application SR');
            // Begin Dialog of application service request
        } else if (stepContext.values.classifiedSR === 'Create Virtual Desktop Service Request') {

            // Begin VDI dialog
        } else {

            // end Dialog
        }
    }


}

module.exports.CreateServiceRequestDialog = CreateServiceRequestDialog;
```

Comment: Can you show your waterfall dialog Steps please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the following code *should* fix your issue.

Correct this:

```js
return await stepContext.context.sendActivity(message);
```

to this:

```js
await stepContext.context.sendActivity(message);
return { status: DialogTurnStatus.waiting };

Hope of help!
```